# sharpdx_direct3d11_effects_x64.dll DLLNotFoundException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, sharpdx

What's the correct procedure for deploying WinForms / WPF Applications which use [SharpDX.Direct3D11.Effects](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpDX.Direct3D11.Effects/) v3 NuGet package?

They seem to depend on two unmanaged DLLs:

- sharpdx_direct3d11_effects_x64.dll
- sharpdx_direct3d11_effects_x86.dll

Should these be copied to the output directory? As a post build step or otherwise?

Comment: It's probably sufficient to just put these files to the output folder (and any other dependencies, too) in a post-built step

Comment: That's what I was thinking - simply copy as a build step. Wondered if there was a clever solution given that it adds an extra step for consumers of any library that references SharpDX.Direct3D11.Effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After we publish the WPF/WinForms applications from Visual Studio, it will generate an Application Files folder which contains .dll.deploy files.

I installed the SharpDX.Direct3D11.Effects package in my WPF application. And after I publish this application, I found the sharpdx_direct3d11_effects_x64.**dll** and sharpdx_direct3d11_effects_x86.**dll** will generate sharpdx_direct3d11_effects_x64.**dll.deploy** and sharpdx_direct3d11_effects_x86.**dll.deploy** files in Application Files folder. We need not to copy to them to output directory.

If the depend on DLLs are not include in your Application Files folder, please configure them through Project Properties -> Publish tab -> Application Files to set the Publish Status for these Dlls as Include.
[image]

Comment: Thats superb, thank you Wendy. Seems the SharpDX makers have thought of a really nice way to deploy these native DLLs!