# SharpDX v4.0.1 sharpdx_direct3d11_effects_x64.dll DLLNotFoundException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, sharpdx

Last year, I asked the question [how to solve a DllNotFoundException for sharpdx_direct3d11_effects_x64.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505374/sharpdx-direct3d11-effects-x64-dll-dllnotfoundexception) with SharpDX.Direct3D11.Effects.dll **version 3**

Now I'm trying the same thing with **version 4**.

I was expecting the two DLLs sharpdx_direct3d11_effects_x64.dll and sharpdx_direct3d11_effects_x32.dll to be added to the Visual Studio project but they are not.

[image]

Has the deployment mechanism for these two DLLs changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got this to work thanks to @Leo-MSFT's answer above.

1. I had to download the [NuGet package from here.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpDX/)
2. Rename to *.zip and unzip
3. Copy the folders runtime/win-x64/sharpdx_direct3d11_1_effects.dll and runtime/win-x86/sharpdx_direct3d11_1_effects.dll to my project and set to Copy Always

This didnt' work so I now copied win-x64/sharpdx_direct3d11_1_effects.dll to the project root and renamed as win-x64/sharpdx_direct3d11_1_effects_x64.dll and set to Copy Always and it worked.

[image]

I'm sure this isn't intentional so I've [reported a bug to SharpDX on Github](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/issues/941).

Answer (score 2):

> Has the deployment mechanism for these two DLLs changed?

Yes, the author of this package xoofx has changed deployment mechanism for these two DLLs from the version `4.0.0-ci120`. You can check the the [4.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/releases) about [Updated D3D11.Effects to the new project system.](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/commit/0317eff9d76bcecaba0d1310951c920355f19299).

Besides, you can download two version of this packages, check the different with [NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/downloads/get/clickOnce/NuGetPackageExplorer.application):

[image]

According to the official document: [Supporting multiple .NET framework versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks):

> If you have architecture-specific assemblies, that is, separate assemblies that target ARM, x86, and x64, **you must place them in a folder named runtimes** within sub-folders named {platform}-{architecture}\lib{framework} or {platform}-{architecture}\native.

So the change in the deployment mechanism is correct.